# How do I make the post request from the express server work in my domain

Tags: angular, express, post, web-hosting

In my component.ts file I have a method that makes and http request to my express server where I send the body of the mail.

The problem is that the post request works when I am in in localhost but not when I deploy to the digital ocean server.

I am not sure how to solve this.

I tried to change the url to the domain I use but no clue how to deal with it.

```
   //component.ts
  callServer(body: any) {

  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        // .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  const Content = {body : body}

  this.http.post("http://localhost:4200/ping", JSON.stringify(Content), {
    headers: headers
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    
  });
}  



//server.js

const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var https = require('follow-redirects').https;
var fs = require('fs');
require("dotenv").config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const router = express.Router();


const port = process.env.PORT || 4200


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/xxxxx'));


app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public',                         
'/dist/xxxxx/index.html')));

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Running...'));

// CORS Middleware
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://xxx.yyy.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  }
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) );



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,         
   Accept, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");    
  next();
 });




app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  let response = req.body
  let mailBody = response["body"]
  res.send(req.body)
  console.log(mailBody)

  sendEmail({
    subject: "Risposta Cessione Del Quinto",
    text: mailBody,
    to: "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    from: process.env.EMAIL
  });

 })


const createTransporter = async () => {
  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"
      );

  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
  });

  const accessToken = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oauth2Client.getAccessToken((err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        reject("Failed to create access token :(");
      }
      resolve(token);
    });
  });

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      accessToken,
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
    }
  });

  return transporter;
 };


const sendEmail = async (emailOptions) => {
  try {
    let emailTransporter = await createTransporter();
    await emailTransporter.sendMail(emailOptions);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be several problems at play. You need to check all of those.

1. Your express server should allow CORS.

```js
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

2. Check that you are using the correct backend server URL for the HTTP service in your frontend (Angular) application. It should no longer be `localhost:XXXX` but your digital ocean server URL instead.

```js
this.http.post(
  "https://<your-digital-ocean-server-url>", 
  Content, 
  { headers: headers }
).subscribe(data => {});
```

Lastly, check if your digital ocean VPC is blocking HTTP requests via the firewall or not. If it is so, you need to whitelist caller IP in the firewall settings or allow public access.

Comment: I tried changing the url but it doesn't work because it says that there is no url matching that post request.

Comment: This is the error I get {headers: G, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://testing.website.com/ping', ok: false, …}